# Props not passing in dynamic URL - TypeError React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am trying to pass props to a component, Location, using React router as a url parameter, however I am getting a type error because  props.match.params.location is undefined. I am passing the location in the url Link of the Locations component and when I click on this link in the browser, it redirects to the correct url with the correct parameter:

```
http://localhost:3000/locations/tokyo
```

However this is triggering this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
at Location (Location.js:10:1)
```

App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <AppNavbar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
                <Route path="/stock-levels" element={<StockLevels />} />
                <Route path="/locations" element={<Locations />} />
                <Route path="/locations/:location" element={<Location />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

```
export default App;
```

Locations.js:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
```

function Locations() {

```
const locations = ["tokyo", "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6", "location7", "location8"]

const locationList = locations.map(location => {
    return <div className="location-container">
        <Card className="location-card">

            <CardTitle><Link to={`/locations/${location}`}>{location}</Link></CardTitle>
        </Card>
    </div>
})

return (
    <>
      <h1>Locations</h1>

        {locationList}

    </>
)
```

}

```
export default Locations
```

Location.js:

```
function Location(props) {

//Make location equal to the location passed via route
const location = props.match.params.location

return (
    <>
        <h1>Location</h1>
        <h2>{location}</h2>
    </>
)
```

}

```
export default Location
```

As far as I can tell, with how the routes are configured and the link url:

```
<Link to={`/locations/${location}`}>
```

This should be passed as props.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In `react-router-dom` v6 there are no longer any route props, i.e. `history`, `location`, and `match`, instead they are replaced by React hooks. `props.match` is undefined and throws an error when trying to then access `props.match.params`.

- `history` object replaced by a `navigate` function via `useNavigation`
- `location` object via `useLocation`
- `match` via a `useMatch` hook, but `params` object via `useParams` was added in v6

The `useParams` hook is what you want to access the `location` route param.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

function Location() {
  const { location } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Location</h1>
      <h2>{location}</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confising in this format, could you plase share your issue in an online sandbox?

https://codesandbox.io/  - is a goood one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `useParams` to get access to the params.

```
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/locations/:location" element={<Location />} />
    </Routes>


import React from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

export default function Location() {
    const { location } = useParams()
    
return (
    <>
        <h1>Location</h1>
        <h2>{location}</h2>
   </>
    )
        }
```

Forgive the spacing.